# Show that a composite linear map is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Let $P \in \Re^{n \times n}$ be an invertible matrix. Define
>
> $$V=\{A \in \Re^{n \times n} | P^{-1} A P \ \text{is a diagonal matrix}\}$$
>
> We define the following mappings
>
> $$L:V \mapsto \Re^{n \times n}: A \mapsto P^{-1} A P$$
>
> and
>
> $$K:\Re^{n \times n} \mapsto \Re^{n} : M \mapsto (M_{11}, M_{22},...,M_{nn})$$
>
> Show that $K \circ L$ is an isomorphism.

To show that $K \circ L$ is an isomorphism we need to prove that K and L are linear and that $K \circ L$ has an inverse.

I know how to show linearity so let's focus on the later. We'll show that $K \circ L$ is injective and surjective.

There's a theorem stating that a linear map $L$ is injective iff $Ker(L)=\{0\}$.

Given $K \circ L:V \rightarrow R^n$, we want to show that $Ker(K \circ L)=\vec 0$. Let $A \in V$. By definition of the kernel, $(K \circ L)(A)=0$. Then we want to see for what values of $A$ does $P^{-1}AP=0$ hold.

$$A=P(P^{-1}AP)P^{-1}=0 \Rightarrow A=0$$

As $0=A \in V \Rightarrow Ker(L)=\{0\} \Rightarrow L \ \text{is injective}$

We're only left to show that $K \circ L$ is onto. To do so, we need to prove that $Im(K \circ L)=\Re^n$. Let the n-tuple $(m_{11}, m_{22}, ..., m_{nn}) \in \Re^n$, which represents the diagonal entries of a diagonal matrix $M$. Thus by definition of the image (let $M \in \Re^n | (K \circ L)(M)=M$ where $M \in V$), $(K \circ L)(M)=M$. Then we want to satisfy the equation $P^{-1}MP=M$

$$P^{-1}MP=M \Rightarrow MP=PM$$

Mmm this is interesting. So it seems that $Im(K \circ L)=\Re^n$ only if $P,M$ commute. Do you agree or I am missing something? Are we done or we must show something else?

---

**EDIT** Let's try TheSilverDoe's approach:

Show that the inverse of $K \circ L:V \rightarrow \Re^n$ exists (i.e. $F:\Re^n \rightarrow V$). By definition of two the product of two maps we have

$$(K \circ L) \circ F : \Re^n \rightarrow \Re^n=Id_{\Re^n}$$.

$$F \circ (K \circ L) : V \rightarrow V=Id_V$$

Show $F:\Re^n \rightarrow V$ is linear.

Let $a,b \in \Re^n$ and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \Re$. We note that $a,b$ are the diagonal entries of two diagonal matrices $A,B$. Thus we have

$$F(\lambda_1 A+\lambda_2 B) = P^{-1}(\lambda_1 A+\lambda_2 B)P = \lambda_1 P^{-1} A P + \lambda_2 P^{-1} B P = \lambda_1 F(A) + \lambda_2 F(B)$$

---

**EDIT 2.0**

Let's show $(K \circ L) \circ F(x)=x$, where $x=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) \in \Re^n$. We'll go from right to left.

$$F(x)=P \text{Diag}(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) P^{-1}$$

$$L(F(x))=P^{-1}(P \text{Diag}(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) P^{-1})P=\text{Diag}(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$$

$$K(L(F(x)))=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=x$$

QED.

Let's show $F \circ (K \circ L)(A) =A$, where $A \in V$. We'll go from right to left.

$$L(A)=P^{-1} A P:=M$$

$$K(L(A))=(M_{11},M_{22},...,M_{nn})$$

$$F(K(L(A)))=PMP^{-1}=P(P^{-1} A P)P^{-1}=A$$

QED.

Comment: Do you know that if a linear transformation is injective between two spaces of the same finite dimension, then it is an isomorphism ?

Comment: I never saw such a theorem,  Could you please prove it ? I do know that two finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension.

Comment: The theorems I had in mind were: a linear map is an isomorphism iff it is invertible and a linear map is invertible iff it is injective and surjective. That is why I used such an approach.

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem ?

Comment: If you know the rank-nullity theorem, try to prove the following : "if $f : E \rightarrow F$ is a linear transformation between two spaces $E$ and $F$ such that $\mathrm{dim}(E)=\mathrm{F}$, then $f$ is injective iff $f$ is surjective iff $f$ is bijective."

Comment: Yes $dimV=dim(KerL)+dim(ImL)$. Ahhh so your point is that as we know $dimV=n$ and $dim(KerL)=0$ then $dim(ImL)=n$. But my point is that we cannot use $dimV=n$ because to do so we need to use the fact that $K \circ L$ is an isomorphism, which we still did not prove.

Comment: Maybe you can prove directly that $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n$ :) Can you give an isomorphism between $V$ and the space of diagonal matrices ?

Comment: If we assume that $K \circ L:V \rightarrow R^n$ is an isomorphism then it is easy to show that $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n$. There's a theorem (3.59 in Axler's Linear Algebra book) stating that two finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension. Thus $n=\mathrm{dim}(\Re^n)=\mathrm{dim}(V)$. But my point is that we cannot assume it. We must prove it. The theorem you stated would prove it. Could you explain it a bit please? :)

Comment: If $D_n$ denotes the space of diagonal matrices, you can show that the image of $L$ is included in $D_n$, and that $L : V \rightarrow D_n$ is inversible : indeed you can check that the application $L' : D_n \rightarrow V$ defined by $L'(D)=PDP^{-1}$ is the inverse of $L$. From that, you can deduce that $\mathrm{dim}(V)=\mathrm{dim}(D_n)$ (which is ?...)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ahhh you're right! What you meant in the first comment is what theorem 3.69 says: having a finite linear operator $L$ the following statements are equivalent: $L$ is invertible, $L$ is injective and $L$ is surjective! Nice so we are done once we show injectivity! :)

Comment: You got it. I just wrote an answer showing another (maybe more direct) way of solving the question, by giving explicitely the inverse of $K \circ L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the most straightforward way is the following. Define $F : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow V$ by
$$F(a_1, ..., a_n)= P \ \mathrm{Diag}(a_1, ..., a_n) \ P^{-1}$$

Prove that $F$ is linear and well-defined (i.e. why its image is included in $V$ ?).

Then, check that $(K \circ L) \circ F = \mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $F \circ (K \circ L)  = \mathrm{Id}_{V}$

Comment: Alright, this is another way of doing it. I used the approach of showing that the linear map is injective. Both are equivalent if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I've tried your approach (please see my edit). Do you agree?

Comment: Hmm your edit is not so clear ! First, you have to *prove* that $(K \circ L) \circ F$ and $F \circ (K \circ L) $ are the identities. Pick an element $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and check, applying the definitions of the maps, that $(K \circ L) \circ F(x)=x$. The same for the other way. Linearity is correct, except that you write $F(A)$, $F(B)$.... whereas it should be $F(a)$, $F(b)$...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I think I proved the identities correctly (edit 2.0 ;))

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely correct now !